# SCP/SSH/SFTP Suggestion on best file transfer strategy

Tags: unix, ksh

I am facing this problem whereby the existing script takes too long to run. On further investigation I figured that it was because for each file that was transfered a new SFTP connection is being made. Of course bulk transfering file will be so much more faster. Are there any suggestion as to bulk transfer the files as well log each file or just the problematic ones i.e files which causes error in transfering only(This is need for easy tracking files for user support purposes).Currently I have tried implementing the script using SFTP/SSH/SCP all of which has roughly the same transfer speed. So any one of these protocols should be fine. I just need some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use file wild cards in your from-files pattern? i.e.

```
cd sendDir; scp newFiles* user@remoteHost:/target/path
```

for example?

You wrote 'of course bulk transfering file will be so much more faster.' I hope you're kidding. Having to restart scp  will not matter for much if your files are taking minutes or hours to send. Presumably the slowest part of the transfer is the time spent 'on-the-wire' sending the data. So ... good comment from @Johnsyweb about using scp compression, but that takes time and can spike a CPU at 100% for ? secs, mins? So how will that affect the other work in process on your sending side. If you're doing this for work, and it will be used a lot, it would be worth testing.

As far as info on problem files, save output from scp to logfile.

```
scp newFiles* user@remoteHost:/target/path > /tmp/yourSystem/scpScriptLogFile.txt 2>&1
```

And review when you think there is a problem OR after you get some error messages captured, make a filter script that emails you info about any problems.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[`rsync`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/osx-10.6.php) is the business.

```
rsync -chavz --partial --progress --stats source_files remotehost.domain:target_dir
```

Where:

```
--checksum             -c              -- skip based on checksums, not mod-time & size                                                                                                                   
--human-readable       -h              -- output numbers in a human-readable format                                                                                                                      
--archive              -a              -- archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H)                                                                                                                         
--verbose              -v              -- increase verbosity                                                                                                                                             
--compress             -z              -- compress file data during the transfer                                                                                                                         
--partial                              -- keep partially transferred files                                                                                                                               
--progress                             -- show progress during transfer                                                                                                                                  
--stats                                -- give some file-transfer stats
```

The great thing about `rsync` is that it only copies what it needs to. So if you run the command a second time, it should copy nothing at all (unless one of the files has changed on either end in the meantime). This is also useful if your transfer gets interrupted somehow. The output of the command above will give you some information on by how much it has sped up your file transfer.

Comment: Right now rsync is not installed in the server. Are the any other way to do the same thing using SFTP/SSH/SCP?

Comment: It's easy enough to install. See http://rsync.samba.org/ . Failing that, you can check the [manpage for scp](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/scp/osx-10.6.php) and tweak your settings for compression, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use some scripting language for which a SFTP module is available.

For instance, in Perl you have Net::SFTP::Foreign:

```
$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host);

for my $file (@files) {
  $sftp->put("$local_dir/$file", "$remote_dir/$file");
}
```

That way the same SSH connection will be used for all the transfers.

Another option is to create an archive file locally (.tgz), and then transfer it and uncompress at the remote host:

```
tar czf - file1 file2 ... | ssh $host tar xzf -
```